# Do precious and pretentious rhyme?

Tags: rhymes

Do the words precious and pretentious rhyme? What are the relevant rhyme rules?

Both words end in « ious » , and they are both pronounced consistently. However, when saying them out loud, they don’t immediately sound rhymable, like other words such as argumentative and tentative.

Comment: It depends on the definition you go with. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme) gives an overview. // "You say 'potato', I say 'potato' " seemed very acceptable, whether we choose a definition that says the different pronunciations rhyme or not.

Comment: Rhyming is about having the same sounds, not spelling or number of syllables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does rhyme but not fully I'd say. A full rhyme would be "contentious" for "pretentious".